# how to add a link that would redirect to another page - in the check out form - woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have a website which is made under WordPress..in that WordPress i am using woocommece to show my products.. when a customer purchase from my website he will be redirected to a checkout page, in there can see a field called "postal code" I want to add a link ("Find your postal code") beside that field which is redirected to another page which is contains all the postal code.. is there any possible way to make that happen?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="direct URL" target="_blank">hyperlink text</a>
```

If you have another formatting for links, insert that snippet inside formatted button.

Comment: can you pleas tell me where can i add this code?? waht is the file that i need to add?? i mean the php page name and place to add this